# Javascript to set div height not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to set the height of two divs on my page, because my page content is dynamic. But it wont work. The height is just one screen of the divs.

The divs contain side borders, thats why it has to be all the way. Any ideas why the height only = one screen height?

```
function bodyHeight() {
    var scnHei;

    if (self.innerHeight) // all except Explorer
    {
        scnHei = self.innerHeight;
    }
    else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight)
        // Explorer 6 Strict Mode
    {
        scnHei = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }
    else if (document.body) // other Explorers
    {
        scnHei = document.body.clientHeight;
    }

    document.getElementById("bgr_right").style.height=scnHei + "px";
    document.getElementById("bgr_left").style.height=scnHei + "px";
}
```

Here is where I call the function:

```
<body onload="bodyHeight();">
```

UPDATE:  + added "px"; but DOESNT WORK EITHER...

Comment: Can you add an alert to confirm that the document/body has a valid Height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only firing once, when the body is loaded.  If you have an event that makes another call to `BodyHeight();` then this should work.

Answer (score 3):

```
.style.height=scnHei;
```

should rather be

```
.style.height=scnHei + "px";
```

The same goes for `.style.width` of course. You forgot to add the unit to the width / height value.

Answer (score 1):

Height and width properties require a unit (either "%" or "px").  Try this:

```
.style.height = scnHei + "px";
```